# BITS using 60%+ of my CPU when using Visual Studio Installer

Tags: cpu, windows-update, visual-studio

When installing Visual Studio community 2019, the VS installer opens Windows BITS.
This is supposed to be a background task yet it is consuming 60%+ of my CPU. This has been the case for the first gig of the 3 gig download and I would like to know if there is something I can to to stop this so that my CPU isn't running at 100% for the entire duration of the download.

[image: See image of tasks]]

Comment: Why is this an issue? It's the installer running and needs to make I/O tasks. Of course it will increase the CPU usage, it's not something you can avoid.

Comment: @CaldeiraG It is an issue because an installation process should not be consuming in total, 90% of my CPU(i5 9400F) and using that much of my PSU(700 watt) which is halting the performance of any other application on my system largely. Especially when the main process is a background task.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with @CaldeiraG. Regardless of what it has been classified as... it is not currently a background task. It is a foreground task. It's not at all unusual for an installation to consume significant system resources. It's not at all unusual for an installation to hamper the performance of other tasks. As far as what has been described so far, this appears to be perfectly normal.

Comment: And also, the installer only runs once so let it run, I'm sure other tasks can wait.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for your response. I guess I was just concerned because I've never known an installation to consume that much, but I stand corrected. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: I'm going to call BS on the answers above.  With BITS on, my VS install was bouncing between 37 KB/sec and 300 KB/sec with 100% CPU usage.  I killed BITS and the performance for the transfer would now go up to about 2 MB sec with 4% CPU.  That is neither background, intelligent, or a good transfer service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it was weird, because both "Windows Update" and "Windows Store" also use the same "Background intelligent transfer service" to download files and in both of them CPU usage is not raising above 2%.

And in "Visual Studio Installer" CPU usage of that service raises above 60%.
But I couldn't find the reason.

To solve this issue, I just terminate "Background intelligent transfer service" process using task manager.

The installer will continue to download and install normally and the CPU usage will back to normal.

---

Visual Studio Installer may redownload the file it been downloading at the terminate moment.